# How to do draw animation effect fill SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gsap

I am trying to animate the SVG logo like drawing fill path without stroke. my logo is looking like that.

[image]

Is it possible to create fill drawing instead of strokes? I saw many solutions about that but all are used by strokes. I also found [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095631/how-to-draw-a-fill-svg) is pretty similar to my problem. but my SVG path is a bit complicated and can't create a fake path with stroke-like they created. I want it growing from nothing and drawing animation effect with fill.

My full SVG code here

```
 <svg
    class="logo-white"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="184"
    height="90"
    viewBox="0 0 184 90.733"
  >
    <path
      class="draw-logo"
      id="logo-path"
      data-name="Path 1"
      d="M84.763,300a45.529,45.529,0,0,0-31.688,12.921l-.009-.009L37.2,328.748,9.482,356.417s-1.207,1.2-1.813,1.81c-.006.006-.012.012-.018.017A18.987,18.987,0,0,1-5.69,363.663c-10.664.118-18.855-7.748-18.965-18.213A18.247,18.247,0,0,1-6.319,326.813c10.148-.112,18.136,6.911,19.128,16.466L33.934,322.07C25.866,308.538,10.8,299.807-6.977,300c-25.612.282-45.29,20.283-45.021,45.763.272,25.694,20.383,45.254,46.566,44.963A46.86,46.86,0,0,0,26.933,377.55c.088-.085.178-.166.265-.252l.285-.285,15.235-15.206c6.542,17.268,22.741,29.1,43.1,28.875,26.209-.291,46.458-20.232,46.175-45.838-.285-25.679-20.775-45.133-47.233-44.842m1.288,63.661c-10.664.118-18.855-7.748-18.965-18.213a18.247,18.247,0,0,1,18.336-18.638c10.776-.119,19.122,7.8,19.237,18.263.115,10.429-7.934,18.469-18.608,18.587"
      fill="#f7f7f7"
      transform="translate(52 -300)"
    />
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because your SVG file is not in the same shape as my logo. can you
>   please tell me how can I modify the path to achieve the exact same
>   shape. I don't have much knowledge about the illustrator by the way.

Unfortunately I do not use the illustrator. Path painted in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.4/)

Open the file from the previous answer to edit the `path` form in`Inkscape`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="logo-white" width="184" height="95" viewBox="0 0 184 90.7" version="1.1">
  
  <path class="draw-logo" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="25" d="m81.3 30.4c0 0-11.7-9.8-17.5-13-3.8-2.2-9.9-4.6-15.3-5-5.7-0.4-11.7 0.4-16.8 2.9-4.8 2.3-8.7 6.3-11.8 10.7-3.2 4.5-5.6 9.8-6.3 15.2-0.9 6.2-0.4 12.9 2.3 18.6 2.7 5.7 7.5 10.6 12.9 13.8 5.2 3.1 11.6 4.8 17.7 4.5 5.8-0.2 11.6-2.7 16.6-5.7 21.6-13.1 34.2-37.9 55.1-52.2 5.8-4 12.1-8.3 19-9.1 5.7-0.6 11.9 0.9 16.8 3.9 6.7 4.1 12.3 10.6 15.2 17.9 2.8 6.9 3.4 15.1 1.4 22.2-1.8 6.3-6 12.2-11.3 16.1-6.3 4.6-14.5 7.8-22.2 7C127.1 77.2 118.6 70.3 111.3 63.7 104.7 57.8 95.9 42 95.9 42" />
  
</svg>
```

[image]

1. Select in the vector editor on the toolbar `Edit contour nodes` <kbd>F2</kbd> (arrow red -1)
2. Edit the shape of the curve by dragging the nodal points and change the length and position of the control levers of the nodal points (arrow red -2)
3. Vector editor saves a lot of overhead information. To remove it, you need to optimize the saved file using  [SVG Editor](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)
4. Replace the old `path` with the new one from the optimized file

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:auto;
padding:1.5em;
background-color:#151515;
}
.draw-logo {
fill:none;
stroke:#F7F7F7;
stroke-width:25;
stroke-dasharray:0,443; 
animation: draw 4s linear  forwards;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
@keyframes draw {
0% {stroke-dasharray: 0,443;}
100% {stroke-dasharray: 443,0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="logo-white" width="184" height="95" viewBox="0 0 184 90.7" version="1.1">
   <path class="draw-logo" d="m78 34.5c0 0-1.3-1.3-1.9-2.1C74.8 30.9 73.8 29.1 72.7 27.4 71.4 26.2 61.9 10.9 46.6 11.2c-5.1 0.1-10.4 1.5-14.9 4-4.7 2.5-8.8 6.3-11.8 10.7-2.6 3.9-4.3 8.5-4.9 13.1-0.9 6.7-0.5 13.9 2.1 20.2 2.4 5.7 6.5 11 11.6 14.3 5.1 3.3 11.6 4.8 17.7 4.5 5.8-0.2 11.6-2.7 16.6-5.7 21.6-13.1 34.1-38 55.1-52.2 5.4-3.7 11.4-7.3 17.9-8.2 6-0.8 12.6 0 17.9 2.9 6.8 3.9 12.3 10.6 15.2 17.9 2.8 6.9 3.4 15.1 1.4 22.2-1.8 6.3-6 12.2-11.3 16.1-6.3 4.6-14.5 8.1-22.2 7-9.7-1.3-20-7.4-24.5-16.1-2.7-5.3-4-10.1-4.4-15.4-0.4-4.7 0.5-11 1.6-14.1 1.9-5.2 8.5-12.4 8.5-12.4" />
 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Great @Alexandr_TT now it's pretty much clear. Thanks for your patience and gave me a clear answer with all possible details.

Answer (score 4):

Your figure is drawn in double stroke

[image]

Therefore, it is impossible to animate its filling with color using `stroke-dasharray`
Consider creating a single outline that runs in the middle of the shape.

[image]

Set the width of this line `25px` and we will animate its appearance by changing the attributes of`stroke-dasharray`

### Animation CSS

```css
.container {
padding:10px;
background-color:#151515;
width:50%;
}
.draw-logo {

fill:none;
stroke:#F7F7F7;
stroke-width:25;
stroke-dasharray:0,425; 
animation: draw 4s linear  forwards;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
}


@keyframes draw {
0% {stroke-dasharray: 0,425;}
100% {stroke-dasharray: 425,0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="logo-white" width="184" height="95" viewBox="0 0 184 90.7" version="1.1">
  
 
 <path class="draw-logo" d="m81.3 30.4c0 0-11.7-9.8-17.5-13-3.8-2.2-9.9-4.6-15.3-5-5.7-0.4-11.7 0.4-16.8 2.9-4.8 2.3-8.7 6.3-11.8 10.7-3.2 4.5-5.6 9.8-6.3 15.2-0.9 6.2-0.4 12.9 2.3 18.6 2.7 5.7 7.5 10.6 12.9 13.8 5.2 3.1 11.6 4.8 17.7 4.5 5.8-0.2 11.6-2.7 16.6-5.7 21.6-13.1 34.2-37.9 55.1-52.2 5.8-4 12.1-8.3 19-9.1 5.7-0.6 11.9 0.9 16.8 3.9 6.7 4.1 12.3 10.6 15.2 17.9 2.8 6.9 3.4 15.1 1.4 22.2-1.8 6.3-6 12.2-11.3 16.1-6.3 4.6-14.5 7.8-22.2 7C127.1 77.2 118.6 70.3 111.3 63.7 104.7 57.8 95.9 42 95.9 42" />
 
</svg>
</div>
```

### Animation SVG

To start the animation click on the black rectangle

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:auto;
padding:1.5em;
background-color:#151515;
}
.draw-logo {

fill:none;
stroke:#F7F7F7;
stroke-width:25;
stroke-dasharray:0,425;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="logo-white" width="184" height="95" viewBox="0 0 184 90.7" version="1.1">
  
  <path class="draw-logo" d="m81.3 30.4c0 0-11.7-9.8-17.5-13-3.8-2.2-9.9-4.6-15.3-5-5.7-0.4-11.7 0.4-16.8 2.9-4.8 2.3-8.7 6.3-11.8 10.7-3.2 4.5-5.6 9.8-6.3 15.2-0.9 6.2-0.4 12.9 2.3 18.6 2.7 5.7 7.5 10.6 12.9 13.8 5.2 3.1 11.6 4.8 17.7 4.5 5.8-0.2 11.6-2.7 16.6-5.7 21.6-13.1 34.2-37.9 55.1-52.2 5.8-4 12.1-8.3 19-9.1 5.7-0.6 11.9 0.9 16.8 3.9 6.7 4.1 12.3 10.6 15.2 17.9 2.8 6.9 3.4 15.1 1.4 22.2-1.8 6.3-6 12.2-11.3 16.1-6.3 4.6-14.5 7.8-22.2 7C127.1 77.2 118.6 70.3 111.3 63.7 104.7 57.8 95.9 42 95.9 42" >
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click+0.5s" dur="4s" values="0,425;425,0" repeatCount="2" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
</svg>
</div>
```

**An additional example of filling the logo from one point with two lines**
To start the animation, click on any letter in the circle

```css
.container {
width:40%;
height="40%";  
  
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="10"  />  
       <!-- The midpoint of the beginning of the animation in the center of the figure. stroke-dashoffset="31.1" -->
 <path id="center" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="31.1" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_C.click" dur="4s" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
   <!-- Middle point on the left stroke-dashoffset="-159.5" -->
     <path id="Left" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="-159.5" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_L.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>  
 
    <!-- Midpoint left top stroke-dashoffset="128.5" -->
     <path id="Top" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="128.5" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_T.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
     <!-- Midpoint lower right  stroke-dashoffset="192.7" -->
  <path id="Bottom" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="192.7" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_B.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>   
 
        <!-- Middle point on the right   stroke-dashoffset="223.9" -->
  <path id="Bottom" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="purple" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="223.9" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_R.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
 
 
 
 <g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
    </g>  
 <g id="btn_C" transform="translate(3 0)">
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="24" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >C</text>
    </g> 
    
     <g id="btn_T" transform="translate(23 0)">
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="24" y="95" font-size="10" fill="orange" >T</text>
        </g>  
  <g id="btn_B" transform="translate(43 0)">
 <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
  <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="dodgerblue" >B</text>
  </g>   
      <g id="btn_R" transform="translate(63 0)">
     <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
       <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="purple" >R</text>
    </g> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexandr_TT it's really helpful. Much appreciated. One thing to ask, how can I achieve the exact same shape of my logo? Because your SVG file is not in the same shape as my logo. can you please tell me how can I modify the path to achieve the exact same shape. I don't have much knowledge about the illustrator by the way.

Comment: @Raydoan Anik Thank you and you Please wait, I will write a little more details